# How to do in Mysql one query to get username and same query to get another username from same users table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table:

```
Users                          Mail
-------                        ------
ID | Username                  ID | UserID | SenderID   | Something
---------------                ---------------------------------------------------
1  | A                         1  |  2     |  1         | Becoming Mad with SQL
2  | B                         2  |  3     |  4         | Mee too
```

I am trying this:

```
SELECT *
 a.userid, a.senderid, a.something,
 b.username
FROM
 mail a
 LEFT JOIN users b on b.id=a.senderid
WHERE
 a.id='1'
```

Output is/similar:

```
a.Userid | a.senderid | a.something | b.username
--------------------------------------------------
2      | 1            | becoming..  | A
```

My Expected output is like this (username B and A in one row):

```
Userid | senderid | something | username | Username of UserID
---------------------------------------------------------------
2      | 1        | becoming..| A        | B
```

How can i get UserID and its Username in the same query? Because i already have `left join users b on b.id=a.senderid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.userid, 
        a.senderid, 
        a.something,
        b.username, 
        c.username
FROM    mail a
        LEFT JOIN users b ON b.id = a.senderid
        JOIN      users c ON c.id = a.UserID
WHERE   a.id='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two copies of the users table, one for the sender, one for the user.

```
   SELECT a.userid, 
           a.senderid, 
           a.something,  
           b.username,
           c.username 
   FROM  mail a,  
         users b,
         users c
   WHERE  a.id='1'
   AND  b.id=a.senderid
   AND  c.id=a.Userid
```

Make sure you put indexes in your tables too for mail's id column and users senderid and user id columns - they'll help speed things up.

Comment: Oh, I just saw the previous answer - both of these do (almost) the same thing. Most people like the JOIN notation more but I'm more used to the other because it is what I inherited from the last DBA on the project I'm working on... The difference is the "LEFT JOIN" will include all the items in the left table regardless if there is a matching entry in the right table.